# Missing orders in Magento 1.8 but are showing paid in Braintree with order number

Tags: php, magento, payment-processing, braintree

We own a magento store and we received payments through Braintree payment gateway. We are seeing two customers orders were processed with some order number and amount has been charged for that transactions in braintree but in the magento store we are not seeing those processed orders so if anyone faced this kind of issue kindly share the steps taken to resolve this type of issues.

Thanks in advance.
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with other PSP's (Payment Service Provider). Most of the time this happens when they only update the order to 'payed' when the customer reaches your payment success page.

Good PSP's make sure they sent the same data via a remote call to your webshops some time later. If the customer hasn't reached the success page, the orders gets updated to 'payed' nonetheless in this way.

In the Braintree extension from Magento Connect ([Braintree Payments](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/braintree-payments-2.html)), I dont see a controller action which is suitable to handle these kind of requests, so I think my above statement is also true for Braintree Payments.